# Is there any way remotely to sign out of Gmail?

Tags: gmail, logout

I logged onto Gmail on a public computer but I don't remember if I logged out.

Is there any way to force that computer to logout without going back to it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Scroll down to the bottom of your inbox page and click "Details" by Last account activity.
[alt text http://i47.tinypic.com/rc61d3.png](http://i47.tinypic.com/rc61d3.png)

On the screen that pops up, click "Sign out all other sessions."
[image]

Comment: Every web app in the world should implement this feature.

Comment: It is a really easy feature to implement. I won't go into detail, but if you tie every cookie you create to an entry in a database, you can just delete all of the cookie records that are connected with that user and suddenly they are logged out everywhere. Really neat feature, I add it to all my apps.